# How to tooltip the headers of the GridView using the list of items in ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` and a list of items in a `ListBox`. Excluding the first column in the `GridView`.

I want to tooltip each and every header with the corresponding item in the `ListBox`. I mean the tooltip for `GridView2.Columns[i].HeaderText = ListBox.Items[i].Tostring()`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < GridView2.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                String header = GridView2.Columns[i].HeaderText; 

                if (header.Length != 0)
                {
                   e.Row.Cells[i].ToolTip = ListBox4.Items[i].ToString().Trim();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is giving me an exception error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Kindly help. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the listbox is populated at this point?

Comment: Do you have the same number of items in listbox as columns in your gridview? If not, you cannot use the same index for both columns and items

Comment: Make sure you have the same numbers of items in both controls or try to iterate through the items in the lisbox instead of iterating through the gridview.

Comment: Yes I have got the same number of items in listbox as columns in your gridview, except the first column header in the gridview.

Comment: make sure you have a `ListBox4.Items[i].count` is more then `GridView2.Columns.Count` if there is `ListBox4.Items[i].count` is less then its always gives you a error like `Index was out of range`

Comment: read this http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/05/how-to-show-tooltip-for-gridview-header.html

Comment: Try to use an ItemTemplate filed and set its HeaderTemplate with a control that has a tooltip like a label for e.g. Take a look at http://forums.asp.net/t/1102549.aspx/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < GridView2.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            String header = GridView2.Columns[i].HeaderText; 

            if (header.Length != 0)
            {
               e.Row.Cells[i+1].ToolTip = ListBox4.Items[i].ToString().Trim();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just suppose to use **Cells[i+1]** instead of **Cells[i]**